# Why does increasing the surface area of the cathode submerged in the electrolyte increase the current in a galvanic cell?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, redox

I can understand why increasing the surface area of the anode would increase the current, because the rate of oxidation will be increased resulting in a greater rate of flow of electrons through the wire to the reduction half-cell. However, increasing the surface area of the cathode also seems to increase the current.

Even though the rate of reduction is increased by increased submersion of the cathode, what bearing does this have on the current?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately I'm looking at galvanic not electrolytic

Answer (score 1):

In an electrolysis, the current increases if the surface of the electrodes increases. And it also increases if the distance between  the electrodes decreases.

Comment: I think you are referring to cell constant $G^* = \frac{l}{A}$

Comment: Yes. I am referring to the cell constant l/A.